# images don't show up using <img> HTML tag

Tags: html, image, github, host, src

I set a  tag to a local path it works normally on my computer **BUT** when I **deploy** it using **GitHub pages services** the images don't load at all

*here is the code:*

```
<ol>
    <li>Go To Apperance &gt; Menu</li>
    <li>Create a new menu by clicking on create a new menu</li>
    <img src="./images/social1.PNG" width="80%" alt="Social Icons">
    <li>Add your menu items as <strong>Custom links</strong> in left side menu</li>
    <img src="./images/social2.PNG" width="80%" alt="Social Icons">
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `src="./images/socialX.PNG"` either to an absolute path or given that you opt for relative paths and under the assumption that the `images` directory is placed inside your website's repository, then its name should be prepended to form the final relative path `src="/repo_name/images/socialX.PNG"`.

Answer (score 1):

I checked [your repository](https://github.com/Ryadh020/HireMe-theme-doc).

Your used relative path correctly, but you missed spell.

In URL, case is sensitive. Your folder name is "Images", but you tried "images", That's why your code not working.

For example, Try `https://ryadh020.github.io/HireMe-theme-doc/Images/front1.PNG` instead of `https://ryadh020.github.io/HireMe-theme-doc/images/front1.PNG`.

Comment: thank you, you helped me a lot. but I have a question if you don't mind, how could you find my REPO?

Comment: @Ferhane Riyadh: You entered your GitHub account name in your StackOverflow profile.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you upload the images as well.

and the link URL is accurate to its file, (I am not sure where the dot is referring, maybe try removing it or add two dots).

Hope you found this helpful :)